# Does "with a view" mean "with a beautiful view"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I am reading a story from *The Economist*. The title of the story is ["No chips, no problem: why old video games are better than new ones"](https://web.archive.org/web/20220228175349/https://www.economist.com/1843/2021/11/24/no-chips-no-problem-why-old-video-games-are-better-than-new-ones).

In this part, the author described the memory each game evokes (emphasis mine):

> “Wind Waker”! That puts me on the 28th floor ***with a view***, where I got my first job as a professional writer at Atlanta Magazine, and video games cut some of the pressure when I couldn’t finish a sentence;

I guess "with a view" here means "with a beautiful view", but I am not that sure.
If I want to describe a place where there is beautiful scenery, can I say a place with a view or a place with a beautiful view? Which sounds more idiomatic?

Comment: _A_ view of the general scenery as opposed to _no_ view at all, against the parking lot, another building, or another wing of the same building. It doesn't necessarily mean _beautiful_ to all tastes — _nowhere_ in Atlanta, Georgia, is particularly beautiful unless you're staring directly into a magnolia tree or plate of ribs — but, yeah, it should be a view of _something_.

Comment: Beauty is in the eye of the beholder.

Answer (score 20):

The phrase *a room with a view* (as in the E.M. Forster novel) usually refers to a hotel room that looks out on the sea, gardens or countryside rather than the car park or another building. The expression doesn't refer to just any place where there is beautiful scenery, though a reference to 'the view' usually implies an attractive one.

Comment: There is no sea, expansive garden, or nonurbanized countryside within view of Atlanta, the source of the Neuromancer "Sprawl", so I don't think E.M. Forster particularly applies in this instance. (Yes, it's the single most famous use of the phrase and generally applies, sure.)

Comment: Many cities have attractice skylines. @lly

Comment: That phrase is specifically about advertising *hotel rooms*, where the rooms with the more interesting view cost extra; it's not particularly obvious to me that it would be used the same way in the context of an *office space*.

Comment: @Barmar Of course Hong Kong has a gorgeous skyline. New York has a classic one. Beijing has a timeless one. Atlanta ain't any of those. You got 4 upvotes so good on ya but your comment is actually off topic _in this instance_.

Answer (score 20):

In the context of the 28th floor of a building, it at least means that the window *allowed the writer to see a long distance*. It usually also means the view was beautiful, but not necessarily.

Comment: I daresay that if that long distance view consisted of a large car park, and a busy motorway, and a bunch of factories with smoking chimneys, then the room would never be described as being "with a view".

Comment: @printf You've obviously never worked in marketing then.

Comment: In hotels "a room with a view" often contrasts with "a view of a brick wall/back alley/the back of the building next door", or if you're unlucky a [light well](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightwell) or even with no windows at all. Hotels which offer views into an internal atrium probably wouldn't call those "rooms with a view", even if it's interesting to look down on the lobby, but some might.

Comment: The implication is generally that it's a nice view, because it's being touted as a feature. If it's not something you'd want to look at, you wouldn't advertise it.

Comment: Unless you're being sarcastic: "I had a room with a view ... of the parking lot!" (I've gotten many of those in my life).

Comment: @Barmar There's no advertising in the context of the question.

Comment: @IMSoP It's not advertising, but they do seem to be referring to it as a benefit of their office location.

Comment: @Barmar As I say in my answer, my guess is that this is in contrast to a window-less cubicle. Even a view of a busy road might be considered a step up from a blank wall.

Comment: @IMSoP On the 28th floor, anything on the road would look like ants. The "view" has to refer to a skyline or vista.

Comment: And I've never heard anyone refer to any window as a view, just to distinguish it from a wall. They'll just say "window office".

Answer (score 8):

Since the context is of an office working environment in the USA, I suspect that this is a reference to the common office layout where the space is divided into "cubicles", enclosing a semi-private work area for each employee.

Frequently (or at least stereotypically) these cubicles cover the entire area of an office space, with many of them opening only towards an interior corridor, and having no direct line of sight to a window. Consequently, a desk next to a window ("with a view") is considered a luxury, perhaps obtained through promotion, or advertised as a perk of a particular company.

See for instance the illustrations on [the Wikipedia page about office cubicles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubicle).

Answer (score 6):

In this case "on the 28th floor with a view" simply means *with an (unobstructed) view out the window*, its not saying anything about the *quality* of what you can see.

It's contrasting a seat "with a view" vs an interior office or cubicle completely enclosed in walls.

It *is* certainly saying something about how nice the office space is; in *some* contexts it might also imply higher seniority within their organization (since presumably some offices have exterior windows and others don't, similar to saying someone has "a corner office"), but in your specific example it sounds like they were just starting as a writer, so I'm not sure that's the implication here.

Comment: "View" implies something about what can be seen outside the windows, it certainly implies something beyond the mere existence of external windows - a street-level office would generally not be described as having a view no matter how many windows it had, and a 28th-story window that faces a brick wall would not be an office "with a view". I agree a view doesn't necessarily have to be beautiful, but it does imply a long line of sight.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie The quote does not say "an office with a view", it says "that puts me ... with a view". I think it's perfectly plausible that that means *a desk with a window*, rather than one without, and I wrote an answer saying essentially the same thing at exactly the same time as this one.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie Sure, having "a view" implies your view *isn't completely obstructed*, but its not saying anything about what you have a view *of*, as the original question asked; it could just as easily be a view of other nearby office buildings and parking garages as it is a beautiful view of rivers and mountains.